# jquery css() is not working with a string

Tags: jquery, css

```
var csn = ['font-family', 'font-size', 'font-weight', 'color', 'text-decoration', 'text-shadow', 'background-color'];

$.each(csn, function (n, value) {
    style.push("'" + value + "':'" + $('div').css(value) + "'");
});

var msg = "{" + style.join(',') + "}";

$('div#taget').css(msg);
```

Comment: What exactly does "not working" mean?

Comment: where is it not working?

Comment: can you tell me what is the error you are getting?

Comment: I'm glad you included a snippet of your code, but you need to have a description detailing your problem and exactly what you are trying to accomplish. Also, some HTML might help, as well. Then we might know for sure whether you have a `div` tag with an ID of "taget" or if it's a typo, which would explain why it is "not working"

Comment: I assume taget is a typo...

Comment: Where are msg, value in css(msg) ,css(value)

Comment: What makes you assume that `.css(value)` will return the css setting for a value, while at the same time `.css(msg)` will set the CSS properties of a div?

Comment: why not adding an eval() on top of that ?

Answer (score 2):

You should pass an object to the css method. `'{...}'` this is a string. This way you are using the `css` method as a getter and not a setter, jQuery tries to find and return the value of the requested property(*that `'{...}`' string*), which is of course `undefined`.

Comment: with all due respect, what did you understand from that question??

Answer (score 1):

Corrected :

```
// use camelCased properties
var props = ['fontFamily', 'fontSize', 'fontWeight', 'color', 'textDecoration', 'textShadow', 'backgroundColor'];

//create a dump object
var dump = {};

//iterate through properties and populate the dump object
for(var i = 0, l = props.length, prop; prop = props[i]; i++)
    dump[prop] = $('div').css(prop);
});

//apply
$('div#taget').css(dump);
```

You should have read [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/css/), where you could have seen some working examples.
Also, you look like having a lack of basics in javascript, objects and so on, so i suggest you visit [this place](http://www.codecademy.com/).

Comment: You should format your "code" as a code-block within the SO editor (Ctrl + K, with the desired code highlighted). This makes code easily distinguishable from the dialogue.

Comment: thanks for the keyboard shortcut :)

Comment: No prob, for a little added info (I find this very useful): Use Ctrl + Clicking on the actual codeblock button to reduce all highlighted lines by four spaces (the opposite of just clicking the button or using Ctrl + K).

Comment: i always used the editor ui, what a shame... thanks again !

Answer (score 0):

I didn't tested, but, try this

```
var csn = ['font-family', 'font-size', 'font-weight', 'color', 'text-decoration', 'text-shadow', 'background-color'];

$.each(csn, function (n, value) {
    $('div#taget').css(value, $('div#source').css(value));
});
```

look that I change **$('div')** to **$('div#source')**, because you want to take the style from just 1 div and not all divs of the page (including *div#taget*);

Answer (score 0):

@Hey,

have changed some things in your code [FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/XvmG3/2/)

Here is the outcome when you see the source of the div.

```
<div id="taget" style="font-family:'Times New Roman',font-size:16px,font-weight:400,color:rgb(0, 0, 0),text-decoration:none,text-shadow:none,background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)">content heer</div>
```