# JQuery apply css stored in variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a div which is to be styled using CSS styles stored in a variable.
Like so:

```js
var styles = 'font-weight","bold"';

$('div').css(styles);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>The Div to be styled</div>
```

This demonstrates what I want to do, but it won't work. Does anyone have any ideas.
Thanks.

Comment: `.css({fontWeight: 'bold'})`?

Comment: Why not use a class and set style using any CSS rule? This is how it should be done imho

Comment: Related: [jquery css() is not working with a string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18082279/jquery-css-is-not-working-with-a-string)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try,

```
var styles = {'font-weight':'bold'};
$('div').css(styles);
```

In your code you are passing a single `string` argument to the `.css()` function. And that is not a supported valid signature with `.css()` for setting up a style value.

```js
var styles = {'font-weight':'bold'};
$('div').css(styles);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>The Div to be styled</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

.css requests either a pair of two strings (rulename and value) or an object with name/value pairs if you try to set a rule. If you only hand one string, it tries to return the value of the rule with matching name (which in your case does not exist).

Try this:

```
var styles = {'font-weight': "bold"};

$('div').css(styles);
```

working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ocgb77m8/